# Transfer counting from views to model in RAILS 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I have this particular `count` function that I want to display in my view:

The first approach is a direct code in my view:

```
<% @consolidated_procurement_monitoring_report.year_table.annual_procurement_plans.where(status: "Approved").each do |app|%>
    <% app.project_procurement_management_plans.each do |ppmp|%>
        <%= ppmp.items.where(type_of_procurement_id: 1).count %>
    <% end %>
```

I want to transfer it into my model but I am not getting the right counting whenever I transfer it there.

Model:

```
 def total_approved_goods

    self.year_table.annual_procurement_plans.where(status: "Approved").each do |app|
            app.project_procurement_management_plans.each do |ppmp|
                ppmp.items.where(type_of_procurement_id: 1).count
            end
        end
  end
```

So in my view:

```
<%= @consolidated_procurement_monitoring_report.total_approved_goods %>
```

Any workarounds will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

oops i finally figured it out

```
 def total_approved_goods
    @count_good = Array.new
    self.year_table.annual_procurement_plans.where(status: "Approved").each do |app|
            app.project_procurement_management_plans.each do |ppmp|
                @count_good = ppmp.items.where(type_of_procurement_id: 1)
            end
        end
        @count_good.count
  end
```

Sorry.